# contract for function that only cares about return value?

Tags: racket, contract

Suppose the following trivial function:

```
(define/contract (foo func)
  (-> (-> any/c ... any/c) #t)
  #t)
```

This is trying (and failing) to express the idea "foo takes a processor function.  I don't care what arguments the processor requires (that's the caller's job) but the processor must return a singular result."

What would be the correct contract for foo?  I've been through the section on function contracts; the above was my first guess but this fails:

```
(foo identity)
; foo: contract violation
;   expected: a procedure that accepts 0 non-keyword arguments and arbitrarily
;     many more
;   given: #<procedure:identity>
;   identity accepts: 1 argument
;   in: the 1st argument of
;       (-> (-> any/c ... any/c) #t)
;   contract from: (function foo)
;   blaming: top-level
;    (assuming the contract is correct)
;   at: readline-input:8.18
; [,bt for context]
```

I also tried this, which apparently isn't even legal syntax:

```
(define/contract (foo func)
  (-> (-> any any/c) #t)
  #t)
; readline-input:10:33: any: use of 'any' outside the range of an arrow
;   contract
;   in: any
; [,bt for context]
```

Comment: Original Q/A: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/YLGstyj-o_U/lhKKctSTBwAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`unconstrained-domain->`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/function-contracts.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fbase..rkt%29._unconstrained-domain-~3e%29%29)